# Nginx reverse proxy for requesting HTTP backend on HTTPS frontend

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, reverse-proxy

I've been seeing a ton of info about reverse proxies and nginx but I'm a little lost on how to implement. I am running two separate EC2 instances (front and back end, with back end running pm2). I have SSL established on the front using LetsEncrypt, and it won't allow me to hit my backend because of Mixed Content. What should I do?

nginx.conf

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name domain;

   location / {}

   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  listen       [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name  localhost;
  root         /insert/root/here;

  ssl_certificate "/path/to/cert";
  ssl_certificate_key "/path/to/key";

  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  10m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

 location / {
 }

 error_page 404 /404.html;
     location = /40x.html {
 }

 error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like browser complains at your html content because it has hard-coded "http://" references to external resources, like javascript, fonts etc.
It does not mean that it can't reach backend due to this "mixed-content" issue.

I see no proxy_pass (or fastcgi_pass) directives in your config (which should pass requests to your upstream backend server) so probably that is an real reason why you can't reach your backend.

Your configuration should look like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /here/are/your/static/files/; # here you can place static html, css, js etc files from your backend to offload backend from serving static files - nginx will take care of them.
    ...
    location / {
        #this means that nginx will forward requests to backend server in case request does not match local static file.
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        #....
        proxy_pass http://backend-server-ip-address:backend-port
    }

}
```

Comment: so I should be running nginx on my backend instance as well? or is this config for the front end?

Comment: well. usage of front-end and back-end terms can be confusing sometimes. some people use term of front-end for the public interface of your service (which could be shop consisting of both client-side-JS, html and server-side)  and backend for them is admin interface of service (which in turn contains both client-side code and server-side code). Other people refer to client-side js/html as front-end and server-side code as back-end. My interpretation of backend in your case is upstream server which does server side processing in general (for both public UI interface and private UI interface).

Comment: @rlax13, if you have two independent servers to provide public functions(for visitors) and private functions (for staff) then please add this information into your question.